# Unbind can't find model that clearly exists

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I'm trying to do a query on a model called uploads, where I search for all uploads that have a given tag. I am using the CakeDC Tags plugin, and I am working from this tutorial, http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-bindmodel-to-get-to-deep-relations. I am trying to overcome the fact that plugin provides two queries (which cannot be searched) by default.

So, I am attempting to do a join via the bindModel function:

```
$this->Upload->Behaviors->load('Containable'); 

    $this->Upload->unbindModel(array(
        'hasAndBelongsToMany' => array('Tag')
        ));

    $this->Upload->bindModel(array(
        'hasOne' => array(
            'Tagged' => array(
                            'className' => 'Tags.Tagged', 
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array('Tagged.foreign_key = Upload.id')
            ),
            'Tag' => array(
                'foreignKey' => false, 
                'conditions' => array('Tag.id = Tagged.tag_id')
            )
        )
    ));

    $tag = $this->Upload->find('all', array(
        'contain' => array('Tag'),
        'conditions' => array( 'Tag.name' => $tagname)
        ));
```

However:  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Tagged.tag_id' in 'on clause'

I believe that this might be because Tagged is just a join table, and not a proper model.
How can I get the table to join as I need it to?

The SQL dump: 
SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
    Upload.id,
    Upload.name,
    Upload.description,
    Upload.created,
    Upload.modified,
    Upload.filetype,
    Upload.numberofviews,
    Upload.numberofdownloads,
    Upload.model_dir,
    Upload.model,
    Upload.owner,
    Upload.license,
    Upload.category,
    Upload.default_picture,
    Upload.soft_delete,
    Tag.id,
    Tag.identifier,
    Tag.name,
    Tag.keyname,
    Tag.weight,
    Tag.created,
    Tag.modified
FROM
    database.uploads AS Upload
        LEFT JOIN
    database.tags AS Tag ON (Tag.id = Tagged.tag_id)
WHERE
    1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as related https://github.com/CakeDC/tags/wiki/Find-tagged-objects is to not do a join at all, and let the plugin do the work for me.

```
$tag = $this->Upload->Tagged->find('tagged', array('by' => $tagname, 'model' => 'Upload', 'link' => 'User' ));
```

Sadly, it seems the Uploads associated information is left out of the query. I'm sure I'll find a way around it.

Comment: Sure. Felt a little weird about marking my own answer as the correct answer. How silly of me.

Comment: If it works, you should always mark it as accepted so others can try the solution if they have the same problem. If another answer comes that you feel is better that yours (explain more the problem, or works magically), you can always unaccept your answer and check the other.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that it can't find the model if you don't tell the association to look for the model in the plugin it belong to. This is not an issue of the plugin but your associations.

```
 'hasOne' => array(
            'Tagged' => array(
                'className' => 'Tags.Tagged',
                'foreignKey' => false,
```

See the plugin name prefix of the className. Same for the Tag model. [See the book.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-models)

Comment: Gave this a shot, and I got the same error. I changed the post to reflect this. I know you made the plugin - please let me know if there is an "official" way to do this. I've literally been spending hours working on this, and have not gotten far.